# Replacing 6v dc motor with 12v dc motor for better speed

Tags: batteries, dc-motor, 12v, conversion

I have a 6v battery powered kids ride-on-toy (with 6v motor). I wanted to make it move faster so I put a 12v battery with the 6v motor which made it run better. But after a while it started moving slow with some smell (from the motor). I felt that I blew up the 6v motor so I replaced it with a 12v motor. But now it's as slow (to start moving) as when it had the 6v motor with the 6v battery. Why is this not working as expected? And how can I make the toy move faster?

Comment: You really haven't given enough information to give a good answer.  My best guess is that the 12 V motor you bought is rated similarly to the original 6 V motor, so you wouldn't expect it to perform much differently.  But as I said, that's just a guess.  The way to make it go faster is to buy a different motor that is rated at a different speed.

Comment: Thanks  that's what I was not sure of, weather 12 v dc motor can have the same speed as a 6 v motor  me not knowing anything bout this thought a 12v would be quicker just cause it was bigger in volts

Comment: @Jonathon - Voltage is irrelevant to power and speed.

Comment: So I need to find a motor with more power and speed there for it will be a bigger motor in size

Comment: You need a motor which is the correct voltage-rating (12v) but which turns faster and is more powerful (so it will draw more current). You need to understand the relationship of voltage, current & power (Ohm's law) to avoid burning more stuff.

Comment: try using a suitable higher rpm 12v motor

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing voltage and power.  The voltage a motor is designed to run at means nothing directly about how fast it can spin or how much power it can put out.

To move your gocart faster, you need more power.  That means a motor that can produce that power at the right combination of torque and speed, and a battery that can deliver that power.  This has nothing directly to do with the voltage the motor is intended to run at.  To some extent, higher power motors will require higher voltages because to get the same power at lower voltage requires higher current, which can cause some problem once you get up to a few 10s of amps for something like a gocart motor.

So the answer is to get the right motor.  This has to be able to deliver a certain power at your desired speed.  There is probably some gearing in your gocart.  By moving it forward manually a measured amount and counting the number of turns the motor makes over that travel distance, you can figure out how fast the motor will spin at your desired speed.  Get a motor rated for the desired power *at that speed*.  This could be a 6, 12, 24 volt or something else motor.  It doesn't matter as long as you can supply that voltage at the required power, plus a bit to cover loss.  Since you already have a 12 V battery, I'd start by looking for a 12 V motor.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a suitable higher rpm 12v motor (of course, with a 12v battery that matches the motor current rating)

Answer (score -2):

Well let me clear it for you budd
Voltage and current are directly proportional 
Increasing Voltage is increasing the Current 
Some motors (DC) are designed for specific current.
When you pump too much current in it.
The motor is just going to say “I can’t take it anymore “ 
But generally More voltage means more current 
More Voltage and current is more power. 
More power means more work done 
As long as the motor CAN handle it.

Now what should you get?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You may not have noticed it, but you answered a question, which was asked five years ago and had already some answers. Please have a look on the other answers to make sure your answer adds something useful to the discussion.